# Sonar Python coverage report issue

Tags: python, sonarqube

Sonar is unable to display code coverage for a Python module generated by Cobertura. I am currently using Jenkins for build and integration with Sonar. My sonar properties are:

```
# Info required for Sonar
sonar.sources=module
sonar.language=py

# Additional Configuration
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=**/nosetests.xml
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=**/coverage.xml
```

and the console output says:

```
12:03:26.458 INFO  - Sensor PythonXunitSensor...
12:03:27.305 INFO  - Processing report 'nosetests.xml'
12:03:27.305 INFO  - Parsing report 'nosetests.xml'
12:03:27.460 INFO  - Sensor PythonXunitSensor done: 1002 ms
12:03:27.460 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor...
12:03:28.216 INFO  - Parsing report 'coverage.xml'
12:03:28.269 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor done: 809 ms
12:03:28.269 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
12:03:28.270 INFO  - SonarBridgeEngine is used
12:03:28.426 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
12:03:29.181 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 912 ms
```

But in Sonar I only see unit test results but no coverage data, and when I ran with debug option it says:

```
16:51:23.124 DEBUG - Cannot find the file , ignoring coverage measures
16:51:23.125 DEBUG - Cannot find the file , ignoring coverage measures
16:51:23.125 DEBUG - Cannot find the file , ignoring coverage measures
16:51:23.126 DEBUG - Cannot find the file , ignoring coverage measures
16:51:23.126 DEBUG - Cannot find the file , ignoring coverage measures
```

I checked cases and paths too but didn't find the issue. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar issue. paths in the coverage.xml file where wrong and I just run a sed command to replace all the files path to add the module directory.

Comment: I had similar issue and found the issue with paths in coverage.xml. After running SED (sed 's/filename\=\"/filename\=\"myprefix\//g' target/reports/coverage.xml), then sonar-runner published coverage report to SonarQube fine. Does anyone know whether sonar-runner has a fix for his yet? Ideally we should not need sed hacks in build. Sonar runner should recognise/resolve paths.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura` to your Sonar properties and run again.